# 2D game development sprite/layout/terrain creation

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

ask a general question. There are few sprite resources and they are hardly liked by me. I would like to learn from the absolute scratch, such as how do I create a sprite from my idea.

Can I ask do I create it this way or what's the standard process?
1. draw it on white paper
2. scan it into a .png jpg etc
3. render it in photoshop

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite right for Stack Overflow indeed, but I have a few suggestions anyway.

If you want to hand draw your art there are a few approaches. I started drawing the resources I needed on paper and scanning them, but this raises a couple of problems.

The first problem is that it can be hard to remove the white background properly leaving nasty bitty edges. This can be solved with time, practice and patience, and as far as I know there is no good way around this.

When using paper, it can be very hard to get clean areas of solid color. Pencils and the like leave and extremely distinctive paper texture, but approaches that give more solid colors using inks tend to go very blotchy.

The other problem is that if you want to animate these, or indeed reuse part of one sprite in another, you're left drawing bits of sprites - this lead me on to my currently favored methodology.

My recommendation would be to use ink onto acetate. You'll need to do some research into the best inks to use, but it means you can build the sprites in layers, much like animators used to do for film back in the day. You still have to solve the white background problem after scanning though, and if you pick the wrong ink it can be very easy to smudge your drawings - not ideal.

The other, more expensive alternative is to use a graphics tablet, and cut out the paper/acetate stage all together. This solves the white background problem, but some people find drawing with tablets oddly difficult - myself included.

Adobe software wise - I would personally use Illustrator while working with a graphics tablet, Photoshop for making adjustments to the resulting images, and Fireworks for building UI interface elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information. That is really helpful. I didn't know there was things like graphics tablet etc.

Comment: You're welcome - some of the Wacom tablets are cheap but still work well - can be a good place to start if you're unsure how you'll get on with one. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a coding question. As far as I know stackoverflow is only for technical problems. That said, I would recommend Illustrator to get started. There are some great tutorials out there. :)